# How to use query in Next.js 13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I used to use query in Next.js 12 like this:

```
  const {
    query: { id }
  } = useRouter();
```

I think it have been changed to `useSearchParams` and can't really find examples akin to version 12, how do you use it in version 13?

Comment: Have you checked the [useSearchParams documentation](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/use-search-params)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using server components inside `app` directory, pages have `searchParams` prop and it automatically populates this prop if you have a query. You do not need to write anything. For example, if you have this `http://localhost:3000/?name=any`, in `page.js`, `console.log(props)`, you get this

```
{ params: {}, searchParams: { name: 'any' } }
```

for the client-side, you can use [use-search-params](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/use-search-params)

Comment: Hi do you have example on how I can utilize this? How do i get the value of props, sorry i'm new

Comment: @CodeGuru I do not have any next13 project on my github but you could create next13 `npx create-next-app` and then google for how to set the app directory